# sending data from checkbox form to next page as string

Tags: forms, asp-classic

I have a list of names that you can tick box to select favourites and then submit the form and it goes to next page to display the short-list.

I need the selected names to send through as `.asp?T=Name&Name&Name` then only show those artists by using

```
`strType = Request.QueryString("T")`
```

with the query

`WHERE`ActName`like '%"&strtype&"%'`

is this possible

The names are originally pulled from a database so generated in loop

how do i do this please?

Thankyou
Michelle

Answer (score 0):

Do not use the `&` Symbol to separate characters in a querystring. The `&` symbol is defined as a type of reserved character in urls (See Here http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/201008/what_characters_are_allowed_unencoded_in_query_strings/).

I would recommend using an underscore as your seperator between values and then using the VBScript `Split` function to achieve the result you want. See Here for more info on Split: http://www.w3schools.com/vbscript/func_split.asp